# Can't get last known location

Tags: android, kotlin

Not gonna lie, I'm very new in kotlin, that why I need analysis of full code.

**On start it asks for permissions (don't need any more it's just test project)
Pressing on the button supposed to change textView to my location**

This is the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var text: TextView


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    text = findViewById(R.id.textView)
    val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    val requestMultiplePermissions = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        permissions.entries.forEach {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "${it.key} = ${it.value}")
        }
    }
    button.setOnClickListener {
        getLastKnownLocation()
    }
    requestMultiplePermissions.launch(
        arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
    )
}


private fun getLastKnownLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        text.text = "do not grants the permission"
        return
    }

    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            if (location != null) {
                text.text = "My location " + location.latitude.toString() + ", " + location.longitude.toString()
            }
            else{
                text.text = "location = null"
            }
        }
} }

//added to Manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**But it wrote "location = null", wats wrong here?**

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxSf9.png)

it don't ask for permissions with emulator, I use connected device for tests

Logcat:

```
2021-10-27 14:51:55.818 10025-10025/? I/ample.idssende: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-10-27 14:51:55.818 10025-10025/? I/ample.idssende: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-10-27 14:51:55.818 10025-10025/? I/ample.idssende: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-10-27 14:51:56.009 10025-10025/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2021-10-27 14:51:56.004 10025-10025/? W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:35158): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7714 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c188,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2021-10-27 14:51:56.009 10025-10025/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2021-10-27 14:51:55.924 16571-16610/? I/MicroDetectionState: Should stop hotword detection immediately - false
2021-10-27 14:51:56.004 10025-10025/? W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:35158): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7714 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c188,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2021-10-27 14:51:56.009 10025-10025/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2021-10-27 14:51:56.004 10025-10025/? W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:35158): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7714 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c188,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2021-10-27 14:51:57.321 10025-10025/com.example.idssender W/ample.idssende: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2021-10-27 14:51:57.321 10025-10025/com.example.idssender W/ample.idssende: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-10-27 14:51:57.321 10025-10025/com.example.idssender W/ample.idssende: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-10-27 14:51:57.321 10025-10025/com.example.idssender W/ample.idssende: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-10-27 14:51:57.321 10025-10025/com.example.idssender W/ample.idssende: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-10-27 14:51:57.452 10025-10025/com.example.idssender W/ample.idssende: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/WindowInsets;->CONSUMED:Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (light greylist, reflection)
2021-10-27 14:51:57.483 10025-10025/com.example.idssender W/ample.idssende: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
2021-10-27 14:51:57.637 10025-10025/com.example.idssender W/ample.idssende: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2021-10-27 14:51:57.640 10025-10025/com.example.idssender W/ample.idssende: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2021-10-27 14:51:58.209 10025-10025/com.example.idssender D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2021-10-27 14:51:58.211 10025-10025/com.example.idssender I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@7ee86fd
2021-10-27 14:51:58.237 10025-10025/com.example.idssender D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2021-10-27 14:51:58.248 10025-10025/com.example.idssender V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@22195f9, this = DecorView@b94e93e[MainActivity]
2021-10-27 14:51:58.254 10025-10025/com.example.idssender E/DEBUG: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = true
2021-10-27 14:51:58.254 10025-10025/com.example.idssender E/DEBUG: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = true
2021-10-27 14:51:58.315 10025-10025/com.example.idssender W/ample.idssende: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Insets;->of(IIII)Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2021-10-27 14:51:58.357 10025-10025/com.example.idssender D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x78180db000)
2021-10-27 14:51:58.382 10025-10127/com.example.idssender I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2021-10-27 14:51:58.382 10025-10127/com.example.idssender I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2021-10-27 14:51:58.382 10025-10127/com.example.idssender I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2021-10-27 14:51:58.383 10025-10127/com.example.idssender D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2021-10-27 14:51:58.383 10025-10127/com.example.idssender E/OpenGLRenderer: Device claims wide gamut support, cannot find matching config, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2021-10-27 14:51:58.398 10025-10127/com.example.idssender D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x78180db000,api=1)
2021-10-27 14:51:58.402 10025-10127/com.example.idssender D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2021-10-27 14:51:58.529 10025-10127/com.example.idssender E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
```

Comment: share logs if any...

Comment: by log it means **Logcat**, you've posted Event Log!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is alright and should work fine.

To make work just open the Google Maps App on your device (real or emulator) and click *My Location Button*.

[image]

Sometimes the Device's last location is null if there is no cached location. Following the above step will ensure the last known location is not null. Re-install the App and it should show you the latitude and longitude of the device's last known location.

***NB*** - You don't need to request for both `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`permission includes permissions for both ***NETWORK_PROVIDER*** and ***GPS_PROVIDER*** so you need to request only the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission

Comment: Just to add the `fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation` will give you the last location from other apps e.g. the Maps App. The best strategy to avoid `null` location would be to request for location updates when the location is null and it will be something like this `fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                        locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper()
                    )` [You can read about it here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates)